# Qt 6 configure options failed

Tags: mysql, windows, cmake, openssl, qt6

I want to build `Qt 6` with prebuilt `MySQL/OpenSSL` libs to try out new features, but I have some issues with configure parameters.

For example, I have such configure parameters:
`configure.bat -debug -static -static-runtime -confirm-license -opensource -nomake examples -no-ltcg -sql-mysql -openssl-linked -prefix "C:\Test\6.0.0\msvc2019_64"`

When I add the `-sql-mysql` or `-openssl-linked` parameters I got the following issue:

```
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:788 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.
```

Also, I have tried to use `-skip qtwebengine`, but `cmake` returns `BUILD_qtwebengine not used by the project`. Some of the parameters does not translate into `cmake` properly. Where I can get full list of `cmake` parameters to build the `Qt 6`?

**[Updated]**

I have translated a few parameters to `cmake`:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DQT_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DINPUT_static_runtime=ON -DFEATURE_ltcg=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\Test\6.0.0\msvc2019_64" -G Ninja C:\QtBuild\qt-everywhere-src-6.0.0
```

But still can not find any docs how to translate those: `-confirm-license -opensource -skip qtwebengine -openssl_linked -sql-mysql`

I have previously built `MySQL` libs by using CMake Option Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-sourcebuild-excerpt/8.0/en/source-configuration-options.html#cmake-option-reference

Is there any similar reference available for `Qt 6`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **lixinwei** (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89993) the issue is resolved. Now, it successfully finds the `OpenSSL` and `MySQL libs`.

**Cmake paramaters:**

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DQT_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DINPUT_static_runtime=ON -DFEATURE_ltcg=OFF -DBUILD_qtwebengine=OFF -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR="C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.1.1i\static\x64\debug" -DOPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS=TRUE -DOPENSSL_MSVC_STATIC_RT=TRUE -DINPUT_sql_mysql=ON -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIRS="C:\MySQL\mysql-5.7.32-winx64\debug\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARIES="C:\MySQL\mysql-5.7.32-winx64\debug\lib\mysqlclientMTd.lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\QtStatic\6.0.0\msvc2019_64" -G Ninja C:\QtBuild\qt-everywhere-src-6.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

list all qt6 features as cmake flags:

```sh
find . -name configure.cmake | xargs cat | grep ^qt_feature | cut -d'"' -f2 | sed 's/-/_/g; s/^.*$/    "-DQT_FEATURE_&=ON"/' | tee all-features.txt

head all-features.txt
    "-DQT_FEATURE_qtwebengine_build=ON"
    "-DQT_FEATURE_qtwebengine_core_build=ON"
    "-DQT_FEATURE_qtwebengine_widgets_build=ON"
    "-DQT_FEATURE_qtwebengine_quick_build=ON"

cat all-features.txt | grep some_feature
```